# How to complete a Polyline in Leaflet.Draw after clicking second point?

Tags: leaflet, leaflet.draw

I am facing a problem when I am trying to draw a polyline using the [Leaflet.Draw plugin](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw).

First, I click on map to plot first point, and then second click to complete line.

However, after I clicked the line a second time, the line doesn't complete itself. It shows a extension to the line.

When I double-click it, the line completes, or else I need to manually click the finish button.  I want to finish that line on second click on map.

This is my code for drawing a Polyline:

```
var drawControl = new L.Control.Draw({
                    position: 'topleft',
                    draw: {                            
                        polygon: {
                            allowIntersection: true,
                            showArea: true,
                            drawError: {
                                color: '#b00b00',
                                timeout: 1000
                            },
                            shapeOptions: {
                                color: '#0033ff'
                            }
                        },
                        circle: {
                            shapeOptions: {
                                color: '#0033ff'
                            }
                        },
                        polyline: {
                            shapeOptions: {
                                color: 'red'
                            },
                        },
                        rectangle: {
                            shapeOptions: {
                                color: '#0033ff'
                            }
                        },
                        marker: false,
                        polyline: true,
                    },
                    edit: {
                        featureGroup: drawnItems,
                        remove: true
                    }
                });
```

Comment: In my case when i double-click then line completes or I need to manually click finish.

Comment: It looks like your post is mostly code.  Could you please provide more details?

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your response.I am facing a problem when i am trying to draw a poly-line from leaflet drawing options.first i click on map to plot first point and then second click  to complete line but after i click second time line doesn't complete itself.it shows a extension. I want to finish that line on second click on map,

Comment: Are you using the `Leaflet.Draw` plugin?

Comment: yes. i used leaflet.draw plugin for draw shapes on map.

Answer (score 6):

You can override `addVertex` function from `L.Draw.Polyline` class, which resides in ***[Leaflet.draw/src/draw/handler/Draw.Polyline.js](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw/blob/master/src/draw/handler/Draw.Polyline.js)***, using `prototype` in javascript, and add the following code at the end of it:

```
        markersLength = this._markers.length;
        if (markersLength == 2) {
            this._fireCreatedEvent();
            this.disable();
        }
```

And, here is the full code:

```
    L.Draw.Polyline.prototype.addVertex = function (latlng) {
            var markersLength = this._markers.length;
            // markersLength must be greater than or equal to 2 before intersections can occur

            if (markersLength >= 2 && !this.options.allowIntersection && this._poly.newLatLngIntersects(latlng)) {
                this._showErrorTooltip();
                return;
            }
            else if (this._errorShown) {
                this._hideErrorTooltip();
            }

            this._markers.push(this._createMarker(latlng));

            this._poly.addLatLng(latlng);

            if (this._poly.getLatLngs().length === 2) {
                this._map.addLayer(this._poly);
            }

            this._vertexChanged(latlng, true);
            markersLength = this._markers.length;
            if (markersLength == 2) {
                this._fireCreatedEvent();
                this.disable();
            }
};
```

Comment: @shaishav shukla Please accept my answer if you find it straightforward. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Adding multiple vertices on polylines (e.g., not finishing polylines automatically on the second click) is a feature of `Leaflet.Draw`.

You may be able to modify this behavior. I recommend that you look at the Leaflet.draw documentation, particularly the [L.Draw.Polyline.completeShape() method](http://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.draw/docs/leaflet-draw-latest.html#l-draw-polyline-completeshape).

Comment: Hi, I tried your solution but i am confuse in this method.can you please let me know which method of  L.Draw.Polyline.completeShape() is use to stop line extending after second click on map.

Comment: I have tried completeShape() method, But it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You can trigger the second click automatically to complete the shape.

```
map.on('draw:drawvertex', e => {

    const layerIds = Object.keys(e.layers._layers);

    if (layerIds.length > 1) {

        const secondVertex = e.layers._layers[layerIds[1]]._icon;

        requestAnimationFrame(() => secondVertex.click());

    }

});
```